# Function modifying list without returning it

Tags: python, list, function, printing, return

I'm trying to make a function to "refresh" a game board not to modify it. My problem is that the function is modifying it and I don't know why.

For example:

```
def refrescartablero(tablero):
limpiarconsola()
copiatablero=[]
columnas=[" "]
print (copiatablero)
for x in tablero:
    copiatablero.append(x)
for x in range(1,len(copiatablero[0])+1):
    columnas.append(str(x))        
copiatablero.insert(0,columnas)    
for x in copiatablero:
    x.insert(0,"")
    x.insert(len(x), "")
for x in range(1,len(copiatablero)):
    copiatablero[x].insert(1,str(x))
for x in copiatablero:
    print ("_|_".join(x))
tablero=copiatablero
return
```

That function adds something to make the board look like:

```
_|_ _|_1_|_2_|_3_|_4_|_5_|_
_|_1_|_ _|_ _|_ _|_ _|_ _|_
_|_2_|_ _|_ _|_ _|_ _|_ _|_
_|_3_|_ _|_ _|_ _|_ _|_ _|_
_|_4_|_ _|_ _|_ _|_ _|_ _|_
```

But I just need to print it. The problem is that the list "tablero" which is:

```
tablero=[[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']]
```

turns into:

```
tablero= [['', '1', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ''], ['', '2', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ''], ['', '3', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ''], ['', '4', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '']]
```

In other words, my function is printing and modifying the list, instead of just printing...

It will be great if someone can help me.

Comment: I think it would be best if you studied the concepts of mutability, immutability, pass-by-value-where-values-are-references, shallow-copying and deep-copying. Currently there is a lot wrong with your code and a complete answer would be very long.

Answer (score 0):

Python lists are mutable. To prevent the original list from being edited, you can pass a copy of the list to the function instead of the original.

```
refrescartablero(list(tablero))
```